# Why are unicode property escapes throwing "Unknown property" errors?

Tags: javascript, regex, next.js, unicode-escapes

The [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) gives examples of matching patterns with unicode support, e.g.

```js
const sentence = 'A ticket to 大阪 costs ¥2000 .';
const regexpCurrencyOrPunctuation = /\p{Sc}|\p{P}/gu;
console.log(sentence.match(regexpCurrencyOrPunctuation));
```

It works fine on stackoverflow as a snippet.

However, in a [javascript codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mayer-mwwh9?file=/src/index.js), the code throws an error:

> /src/index.js: Unknown property: Sc

In a `Next.js` codesandbox it also throws the same error.

On the other hand, on regex101 website the pattern is correctly matched to the sentence, with ECMAScript flavor and with "gu" flag.

Additionally, in my real world `Next.js` `Typescript` project, a pattern `/\P{L}/gu` worked fine until yesterday when I upgraded all dependencies to latest versions. Now it throws similar error with `strict` mode set to true in tsconfig.json. With `strict` mode set to false it still works fine.

Why is this error occurring and how to use the `/\p{Sc}|\p{P}/gu` or `/\P{L}/gu` regex pattern in code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the documentation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-nonbinary-unicode-properties), `Sc` is a *non-binary* property. Which means you can't just use `\p{Sc}`; you have to use `\p{Sc=some_script_name}`, where the script name is taken from [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's a bug in next.js: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19303